# ggplot2's ggsave function crunches together all the layers and labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm not sure how else to explain, I think an image is probably best.

Here's the output from the plots pane of studio:
[image: Here's the output from the plots pane of studio.]

Here is what get's stored by ggsave:

[image: Here is what get's stored by ggsave.]

Here's the code used to produce the images:

```
df %>% filter(!is.na(Arrival.Delay.in.Minutes)) %>% 
    # Select numeric columns
    select(Age, Flight.Distance, Departure.Delay.in.Minutes, Arrival.Delay.in.Minutes) %>% 
    # Calculate correlations
    cor(.) %>% 
    # Round off values
    round(., 2) %>% 
    # Melt (wide to long) the data for plotting
    melt(.) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = X1,y = X2, fill=value)) +
    geom_tile(color= "white") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, 
                                     size = 9, hjust = 1)) +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "gray", 
                         midpoint = 0, limit = c(-1,1), space = "Lab", 
                         name="Correlation",guide = guide_colorbar(barheight = 4)) +
    coord_fixed() +
    geom_text(aes(X2, X1, label = value), color = "black", size = 2) +
    labs(title = "Correlation of Numeric Variables") +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())

    
ggsave(filename="correlation_of_numeric_vars.png", path="Visualizations/", 
       width =521, height=532, units="px")
```

This may come as a shock, but I would prefer the second output to appear more similar to the first.

Comment: Try setting your `dpi` to something like `72` in the `ggsave()` call.

Comment: Or you could add `theme_gray(base_size = 4)` to the plot to shrink the size of all the plot elements.

Comment: Those both look a little off, but it seems like switching to width =6, height=6, units="in" has  normal looking proportions.